# Legendre transforms for the Ising model

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model

I'm reading a review on the Ising model and came across a section where they discuss Legendre transforms of thermodynamic potentials. Now I'm familiar with the classical thermodynamic relations such as $F = U - TS$ (Helmholtz), $G = F + pV$ (Gibbs) and so on, but fail to see the connection with the ones proposed for spin models. In particular, the authors define (for $\beta=1/T=1$)

$$ F(J, h) = - \ln{Z(J, h)}, $$

$$ S(\chi, m) = \min_{J, h}\left[{-\sum_{i} h_i m_i -\sum_{i < j} J_{ij} \chi_{ij} - F(J, h) }\right], $$

$$G(J, m) = \max_{h}\left[ { \sum_{i} h_i m_i + F(J, h)} \right] $$

Now I fail to see how this relates to thermodynamic potentials in terms $N, V, T$ and so on now that we are working with a spin model. Is there a logical derivation for why $S$ and $G$ should follow these functional forms?

Comment: Are they actually defined with $\min$ operators? Also, the meaning of $\chi$ is not clear.

Comment: Yes, the min and max operators are also a bit confusing, but perhaps they assume that in equilibrium the min/max is attained. 
This is the paper in case you're interested: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.01522.pdf (section 2.2.5).
Corrected the formula with $\chi$ now.

Comment: $\min$ might have to do with a more formal definition of the Legendre transformation in terms of the dual problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of spin models one often uses Legendre transformation to switch between the magnetic field and magnetization as the independent variable. The magnetic field and the magnetization are obviously specific to this context, which is why the potentials obtained do not have special names for them. The interchange of the external and the response variables is however quite generic to thermodynamics. Some TD textbooks cover it explicitly in abstract terms, while the others limit to the particular case of $p$ and $V$ - which is the model to follow.

Comment: So in my reference they call $F(J, h)$ the Helmholtz free energy, which is logical given its definition from the partition function. But called $G(J,m)$  the Gibbs free energy seems a bit arbitrary, since there's no reason why $h_i$ and $m_i$ should play the role of $p$ and $V$.

Comment: It is obtained in the same way, up to replacement $V \rightarrow h, p \rightarrow m$. In the Helmholz free energy the independent variable is $V/h$, while the response variable is $p/m$; in the Gibbs free energy the other way round. Physics is different, but on the abstract level of switching the independent/response variables it is the same thing.